# Is it advisable to paint interior walls with a sprayer?

Tags: painting, spraypainting

We just purchased a house and before moving in we want to paint all the rooms: 4 bedrooms, living room, kitchen, and family room (2000 sft home). Being we want to be as efficient as possible I had looked into using a power sprayer. I've read both pros and cons on doing this so hoping to seek some answers from people here that have done this before.

So, using a sprayer inside, yes or no? If yes, what tips and precautions would you suggest?

Comment: Wait... You've read both pros and cons elsewhere, and have come here for **more** pros and cons? Unfortunately, You'll probably get the **same** pros and cons here.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. The answer I accepted stated something that the other articles I read never pointed out. So in my opinion it made it worth asking.

Comment: I was impressed with my painter.... It took two guys to do it:  one sprayed while the other rolled the same area.  Impressive!

Comment: It's helpful that you asked the question here to help others avoid the same repeated research.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pro: Quick TO PAINT. ONLY.

Con: you have to mask everything, but EVERYTHING, you don't want covered in paint. Floors, windows, toilets, sinks, outlets, switches, lights, the works.

Con: not good if you want more than one color, or yet more masking needed.

Apartment complexes that paint everything white and replace the carpets (and nearly everything is carpeted) afterwards find them "efficient" - most other people get the whole job done a lot faster with a roller and brushes.

Comment: Thanks, as we are doing multiple rooms with different colors in each room (and sometimes multiple colors in the same room) spraying may not work for us. Rollers and brushes it is then.

Comment: When we built our house (acted as our own general), I sprayed all of the primer, then sprayed the ceiling with color since we were using the same color for the ceiling throughout. Went back and rollered the walls. But yes, over spray happens extensively. Spot on with your answer here.

Comment: This is why nearly all rooms are painted with spray in new construction (prior to windows and flooring ad trim going in) but not existing construction (way too much work to mask everything).

Answer (score 10):

When I did my house, I used a sprayer.  But everything was getting ripped out, floors, doors, trim and light fixtures.  Masking was simple because of this and being able to do the entire house in about 8 hours of work over two days paid for the extra paint and sprayer.  This was a coat of primer and 1 to 2 coats of paint.  The 3 rooms I didn't spray was the kitchen and bathrooms.  If was going to repaint a room now, I would go with a brush and roller.

When I say extra paint, I mean extra paint.  I used about 25% more paint than I would have if I used a brush and roller.

Answer (score 3):

If you plan on doing A LOT* of painting, then yes; use a paint pump with a roller attachment.

Electric Airless Paint Sprayer:

[image]

([runyonrental.com](http://www.runyonrental.com/Electric-Airless-Paint-Sprayers.dept))

*A LOT= You are a painter or a landlord. Breaking down and cleaning these systems can take hours (if you expect it to work the next time).

Comment: It takes about a half hour to clean up mine, but yes, takes a bit of time. Also, when finished, load the sprayer with something like [Pump Armor](http://www.graco.com/us/en/products/contractor/pump-armor.html) so the pump does not get seized between uses.

Comment: I was considering getting one of those Wagner Power Rollers at home Depot figuring it would make things a little faster. The above might be overkill for a one time painting.